# Projection of arrays using $ vs using $slice

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection as follows:-

```
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
```

I am using following query:-

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } },
                  { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

I am getting result as:-

```
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 87 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 90 ] }
```

Now my question is that when i use $gte on fields grades, It will check if any element of array matches condition and if it does it return the document. So why am i getting output of first document as 87 and not 70. I know that we have specified an equality condition "grades: { $gte: 85 }" but it has returned me the complete document and projected the first field. Then why 87 is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why am i getting output of first document as 87 and not 70.

Because you specifically asked for it. This is precisely what the [positional projection operator `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) is for: it returns the *first* element that matched the query, so the projection `grades.$ : 1` will return an array that contains the first and only the first element in the array *that matched the criterion*, i.e. the first element greater than or equal 85.

It might be irritating that it's still an array - after all, since it's always only one element, they could just provide you with the value like `grades:87`. This is a pattern in MongoDB, though: it won't modify the structure of your data unless you use the aggregation framework, making it easier to map the query results to your statically typed languages.

If you want to have the whole array instead, you wouldn't need the projection at all:

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } } )
{ "_id" : 1, semester: 1, "grades" : [  70,  87,  90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, semester: 1, "grades" : [  90,  88,  92 ] }
```

If you only want the first element in the array (not the first *matching* element), you could use [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/):

```
db.students.find({semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } },{ "grades": {$slice : 1}});
{ "_id" : 1, semester: 1, "grades" : [  70 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, semester: 1, "grades" : [  90 ] }
```

Comment: I have a doubt here, what I have in my mind is that when we query anything with projection then the two things happen.
1)A cursor is returned with the documents that satisfy the criteria so in this case it is { "_id" : 1, semester: 1, "grades" : [  70,  87,  90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, semester: 1, "grades" : [  90,  88,  92 ] }.
2)Now the projection applies and we get the first element that is 
{ "_id" : 1, semester: 1, "grades" : [  70 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, semester: 1, "grades" : [  90 ] }
So why 87 comes in first field?
Do $ has any intelligence??

Comment: The projection is part of the cursor, it's not a secondary operation that happens *after* the cursor has returned results, but is used during cursor iteration, so it has knowledge about the matching process, yes, otherwise it wouldn't be able to do what it does.